# How to append array rowwise in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have two numpy arrays:

```
a = np.array([[0,0,1],
              [0,1,0],
              [0,1,1],
              [1,1,1],
              [1,1,0],
              [0,0,0]])
b = np.array([9,9,9])
```

What is the easiest way to append array b into each row of array a?

The output should look like this:

```
c = np.array([[0,0,1,9,9,9],
              [0,1,0,9,9,9],
              [0,1,1,9,9,9],
              [1,1,1,9,9,9],
              [1,1,0,9,9,9],
              [0,0,0,9,9,9]])
```

Answer (score 3):

One way using [`broadcast_to`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) and [`hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```
c = np.hstack([a, np.broadcast_to(b, (a.shape[0], b.shape[0]))])
```

output:

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 9, 9, 9],
       [0, 1, 0, 9, 9, 9],
       [0, 1, 1, 9, 9, 9],
       [1, 1, 1, 9, 9, 9],
       [1, 1, 0, 9, 9, 9],
       [0, 0, 0, 9, 9, 9]])
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to expand array `b` and then append to array `a`

```
>>> np.append(a, b.repeat(len(a)).reshape((len(a),len(b))), axis=1)

array([[0, 0, 1, 9, 9, 9],
       [0, 1, 0, 9, 9, 9],
       [0, 1, 1, 9, 9, 9],
       [1, 1, 1, 9, 9, 9],
       [1, 1, 0, 9, 9, 9],
       [0, 0, 0, 9, 9, 9]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, using [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
np.array([x + b.tolist() for x in a.tolist()])
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 9, 9, 9],
       [0, 1, 0, 9, 9, 9],
       [0, 1, 1, 9, 9, 9],
       [1, 1, 1, 9, 9, 9],
       [1, 1, 0, 9, 9, 9],
       [0, 0, 0, 9, 9, 9]])
```

---

Yet another possible solution, using [`numpy.fromiter`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html) and [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain

(np.fromiter(chain.from_iterable(np.concatenate((x, b)) for x in a), int)
  .reshape((a.shape[0], a.shape[1] + b.shape[0])))
```